# Azure DevOps, setting up a job that depends on multiple jobs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up an azure pipeline using YAML with some jobs, I have one job that depends on multiple other jobs.

jobs:

- job: A
  ...
- job: B
  ...
- job: C

  **dependsOn: A, B**

running this code gave me an error 'Job Artifact depends on unknown job A,B.'

Answer (score 39):

I corrected the sysntax

```
- job: C

  dependsOn:
    - A
    - B
```

Comment: Is there a way to set dependency via classic editor (not yaml?)

Answer (score 19):

Adding conditions to the above answer. If either one of the job needs to be successful for job C to get started.

```
- job: C
  dependsOn:
    - A
    - B
  condition: |
    or
    (
      eq(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded'),
      eq(dependencies.B.result, 'Succeeded')
    )
```

[This article might help](https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-pipelines-depends-on-with-conditionals-in-yaml/)